# Allow Spring to have multiple WebMvcConfigurer implementations in different jars

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, interceptor, spring-web

When using Spring Web, in this case for rest endpoints & using Spring Boot 2, I can configure interceptors for my app using by implementing the `WebMvcConfigurer` interface:

```java
@Configuration
public class SpringWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/api/endpoint/**");
    }
}
```

I added this interceptor to most of my apps in an automatic fashion by doing the following:

1. Create a "common-jar", and put the above interface under package
   `com.company.api`.
2. In every app, add the package `com.company.api` to
   the api scan.

This common package also contains the Interceptor and utility classes to make this interceptor work, so in effect, adding this common-jar would automatically add he interceptor to all operations in the app, which is a similar concept as to what Spring itself does: adding dependencies changes the default configuration of Spring.

The problem I'm facing now is this approach cannot be extended to a second interceptor in a second jar, because I already used the `WebMvcConfigurer` implementation. and I cannot have two.

I was thinking about maybe using some kind of composite-configurer pattern where we loop over every configurer, collect all interceptors, and then add them once, but unfortunately Spring doesn't allow this. What are my options?

Currently, the approach I took is duplicating the `WebMvcConfigurer` interface in every app that requires it. I feel sad when something changes, and I have to change the same snippet of code in every single app.

Comment: _"The problem I'm facing now is this approach cannot be extended to a second interceptor in a second jar, because I already used the WebMvcConfigurer implementation. and I cannot have two."_ Why shouldn't you be able to use multiple implementations of WebMvcConfigurer?

Comment: Spring does allow multiple `WebMvcConfigurer`, what's your real problem?

Comment: Don't you think API Gateway pattern will help you here? Just one API Gateway will help you out manage multiple things? Just a thought.

Comment: @DirkDeyne Well, if implementation A returns a registry with only interceptor A, and implementation B returns a registry with only interceptor B, would spring combine both registries into one super registry containing both A and B, or would it just pick one, or would it throw an error that there was no unique bean definition ?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn see the comment to DirkDeyne. Where is it documented that multiple `WebMvcConfigurer`'s are allowed and how do they behave if they both implement the same stuff (in this case an InterceptorRegistry)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly , basically you want to define some common `Interceptors` in multiple JARs such that an application can activate these `Interceptors` by simply including these JARs into their app ?

> I was thinking about maybe using some kind of composite-configurer
>   pattern where we loop over every configurer, collect all interceptors,
>   and then add them once, but unfortunately Spring doesn't allow this.
>   What are my options?
>
> Well, if implementation A returns a registry with only interceptor A,
>   and implementation B returns a registry with only interceptor B, would
>   spring combine both registries into one super registry containing both
>   A and B, or would it just pick one, or would it throw an error that
>   there was no unique bean definition ?

Actually , Spring has already implement [this feature](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4b8ce04bdc45c0e523a2b2e140cdc6b4f8db858a/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java#L45). When there are multiple `WebMvcConfigurer` beans , Spring simply [loop them one by one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3a0f309e2c9fdbbf7fb2d348be861528177f8555/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java#L86) and calls their configuration methods. So the end-result is that `InterceptorRegistry` will contain all interceptors.

If the client application need to activate certain `WebMvcConfigurer` only, it can simply exclude those JARs containing the `WebMvcConfigurer` that they don't want.

To take this idea further which allow the application to control which `Interceptors` to activate down to interceptor level , you could even do the following in each common JAR :

```
@Configuration
public class SpringWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    //Make sure the HandlerInterceptor implementation in this JAR is a bean (e.g mark it as @Component)
    @Autowired
    private List<HandlerInterceptor> interceptors;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        for(HandlerInterceptor interceptor : interceptors){
            registry.addInterceptor(interceptor).addPathPatterns("/api/endpoint/**");
        }
    }
}
```

In the client application , use `includeFilters` / `excludeFilters` in `@ComponentScan` to customise which to interceptors to include. For example, to disable certain `Interceptors`, you could do :

```
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {"com.company.api"},
    excludeFilters={
         @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=com.company.common.jar1.Inteceptor1.class) ,
         @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=com.company.common.jar2.Inteceptor1.class)
    })
```

Comment: Is the CompositeWebMvcConfigruer "active by default", meaning that the result of all of webmcvconfigurers is "summed up" by default?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, you don't want to implement all the methods of `WebMvcConfigurer`  in every app. You just want to add relevant interceptors and be done with it.

My approach would be to create an `AbstractWebMvcConfigurerImpl` by implementing the `WebMvcConfigurer` in the `Common` module. Just leave the `addInterceptors()` abstract and implement other methods. You can then extend that abstract implementation in your every Spring Boot project and just override the `addInterceptors()` method as per your need.

Also, you can have as many implementations of `WebMvcConfigurer` as you want in a Spring project. So, if you need to define some common interceptors in the `Common` module, you can extend the `AbstractWebMvcConfigurerImpl` in the common module also.

Please note that all your implementations of `AbstractWebMvcConfigurerImpl` should be annotated with `@Configuration`